# creating a two dimensional std::vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, stdvector

I want to create a two-dimensional vector where the first dimension is constant by the second dimension is different, for example

```
int const mysize = 3;
int vecSizes[3] = {7, 2, 10};
vector<vector<int>> out_buff(mysize);
```

I want my inner vectors to be according to the sizes in `vecSizes` as the following

```
out_buff[0] // has size 7
out_buff[1] // has size 2
out_buff[2] // has size 10
```

I do not want to use `push_back` or `resize` because it takes time when using large vectors, is there a way to do that?

Comment: "I do not want to use push_back or resize because it takes time" - well, of course it takes time. You're not going to find a solution that doesn't take time. The amount of time taken by `push_back` should be reasonable, and there's always `emplace_back` if you can't even accept the cost of the moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in a `std::vector` have to be constructed, so in order to create the vectors of the size you want, you will have to use `push_back` or `resize` (preferably `resize` because it only will perform 1 allocation)

One alternative could be instead of actually changing the size, just calling `reserve`, which just allocates memory but doesn't actually insert any elements. The reported size will still be zero, but `capacity` will return at least what was passed to `reserve`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete program with minor modifications to OP's code. Note the assertions (i.e. verifications) of the sizes and capacities.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  enum {N = 3};
  int const vecSizes[N] = {7, 2, 10};
  vector<vector<int>> out_buff{N};

  assert(out_buff.size() == N);
  assert(out_buff.capacity() == N);

  for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    out_buff.at(i).reserve(vecSizes[i]);
  }

  int i = 0;
  for (auto const& vec : out_buff) {
    assert(vec.size() == 0);
    assert(vec.capacity() == vecSizes[i++]);
  }
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/ikm1LR